# Programmatically route with wmr / preact-iso?

Tags: preact, preact-router

I've been playing with [wmr](https://github.com/preactjs/wmr) and [preact-iso](https://github.com/preactjs/wmr/tree/main/packages/preact-iso) and coming from preact-cli, preact-router, etc, I'm a bit confused on how to do some of the things I used to be able to do.

Case in point: preact-router's `route()` function seems to be missing from preact-iso's router package.

How would I route from code?

I used to be able to do this:

```js
import { route } from 'preact-router';

// Send the user to /path
route('/path');
```

So how would I do that with WMR / preact-iso?

And somewhat related: Is there any way I can use the `<Link />` component with preact-iso?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`route()` exists upon the `useLocation` hook.

```js
import { useLocation } from 'preact-iso';

const location = useLocation();

location.route('/error');
```

Edit: Missed your question about `<Link>`. You can create this yourself, we don't ship an equivalent. It's just a shallow wrapper around an anchor tag.

Here's a pretty direct copy:

```
function Link({
    class: c,
    className,
    activeClass,
    activeClassName,
    ...props
}) {
    const inactive = [c, className].filter(Boolean).join(' ');
    const active = [c, className, activeClass, activeClassName].filter(Boolean).join(' ');
    const matches = useLocation().url === props.href;

    return <a { ...props } class={matches ? active : inactive} />;
}
```

Comment: Ah I was looking in the wrong spot! Thanks! I still use Class Components quite a lot (yeah, I know...). From a quick look at the source, I think I should be able to get a hold of route via the LocationProvider context, too, right?

Comment: Yep, should be able to.

Comment: Ok sorry to bother you again but the only way I've gotten it to work with Class Comps is wrap elements in `<Router.Provider.ctx.Consumer />` and doing the whole [createContext()](https://preactjs.com/guide/v10/context#createcontext) thing where I pass a callback to the Consumer component. There must be an easier way..? Also, VSC complains Prodiver doesn't exist on Router, but it works just fine 

Comment: Ended up asking the above question and turn it into a feature request: https://github.com/preactjs/wmr/issues/930